# Advanced XSLT Transformation for XML to XML Conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, data-transform

I have an XML which looks like this:

```
<root>
<name>
    <elements T="BI" S="1">1</elements>
    <elements T="BI" S="2">2</elements>
    <elements T="BI" S="3">3</elements>
</name>
<name>
    <elements T="BM" S="1">10</elements>
    <elements T="BM" S="2">20</elements>
    <elements T="BM" S="3">30</elements>
</name>
<name>
    <elements T="XX" S="1">001</elements>
    <elements T="XX" S="2">002</elements>
    <elements T="XX" S="3">003</elements>
</name>
<name>
    <elements T="XX" S="1">005</elements>
    <elements T="XX" S="2">007</elements>
    <elements T="XX" S="3">009</elements>
</name> </root>
```

and i am trying to use the following XSLT transformation to convert this XML into another XML:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root">
<name_code_1>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_1>
<name_code_2>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '2'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_2>
<name_code_3>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '3'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_3>
<name_code_4>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_4>
<name_code_5>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '2'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_5>
<name_code_6>
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:for-each select="element[not(@T=../preceding-sibling::*/element/@T)]">
            <xsl:if test="@T = 'XX' and @S = '3'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(),1,1000)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</name_code_6> </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to flatten out the name tags where  T-attribute= "XX"and based on S-attribute ="1" or "2" or so on... populate these elements into 6 different XML tags as shown below. *The above logic is not working*. Can someone please help me by providing some suggestions as to how to address this problem.

Below is the desired final output:

```
<some_tag>
<name_code_1>001</name_code_1>
<name_code_2>002</name_code_2>
<name_code_3>003</name_code_3>
<name_code_4>005</name_code_4>
<name_code_5>007</name_code_5>
<name_code_6>009</name_code_6> </some_tag>
```

Thanks
Qubiter

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using the `position()` function to get the node index from a subset of `elements` nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />                              <!-- remove superfluous text() nodes -->

  <xsl:template match="/root">                                 <!-- main match and creation of <some_tag> element -->
    <some_tag>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name/elements[@T='XX']" />  <!-- create subset of nodes with attribute @T='XX' -->
    </some_tag>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elements">                              <!-- match elements from subset list -->
    <xsl:element name="{concat('name_code_',position())}">     <!-- concat position to node-name -->
      <xsl:value-of select="." />                              <!-- copy value -->
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<some_tag>
    <name_code_1>001</name_code_1>
    <name_code_2>002</name_code_2>
    <name_code_3>003</name_code_3>
    <name_code_4>005</name_code_4>
    <name_code_5>007</name_code_5>
    <name_code_6>009</name_code_6>
</some_tag>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This approach is using for-each-group and this is the best method if you are using XSLT 2.0.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="name/elements" group-adjacent="if(@T='XX') then 'element' else 'cc'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'element'">
                    <some_tag>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:variable name="ss" select="position()"/>
                            <xsl:element name="{concat('name_code_', $ss)}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </some_tag>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Below is output generated by above XSLT.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<some_tag>
   <name_code_1>001</name_code_1>
   <name_code_2>002</name_code_2>
   <name_code_3>003</name_code_3>
   <name_code_4>005</name_code_4>
   <name_code_5>007</name_code_5>
   <name_code_6>009</name_code_6>
</some_tag>
```